# Unpackaging vagrant box failed

Tags: vagrant

I packaged a vagrant VM into a box and am attempting to unpackage said machine on a different computer.

It gives me the following error:

> The box failed to unpackage properly. Please verifty that the box file youŕe tring to add is not corrupted and try again. The output from attempting to unpackage (if any):
>
> x ./vagrant_private_key
>
> x ./box-disk1.vmdk: truncated gzip input
>
> bsdtar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.

I packaged the box on an Ubuntu system and get the same error when trying to unpackage on another Ubuntu system as well as on a Windows system. Does anyone know the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible that you had an error during packaging the box - if you run out of space on the initial ubuntu, you would not have a clear error message but not everything is added to the zip and you get this error message during unpackaging